# Can one module read another module's bean?

Tags: spring-boot, maven-module

I have two SpringBoot modules. `commons` and `web`.

In `commons` module, I define a bean:
[image]

And I can get this bean In the `commons` test
[image]

But unfortunately, I can not get the bean from anther module.
[image]

Am I mistake something? I want to get the bean which defined in the `commons` module from my `web` module.

this is my ModulesApplication.java

```java
package com.github.fish56.modules;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ModulesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ModulesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ModulesApplicatonTest.java

```java
package com.github.fish56.modules;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class ModulesApplicationTest {
    @Test
    public void isEnvOk(){}
}
```

## Update： it works

Comment: Could you please add ModulesApplication class code?

Comment: @JonathanJohx yes, I add some additional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(
  classes = {CommonsApplication.class, ModulesApplication.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ModulesApplicationTest {
    @Autowired
    private YmlConfig ymlConfig;

    @Test
    public void isEnvOk(){}
}
```

Also, your `YmlConfigTest` should extend `ModulesApplicationTest` class.

Comment: @bitfishxyz Can you post your project on Github?

Comment: @bitfishxyz You can accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have access to beans defined in one Spring application from another. This is because each Spring application manages its beans separately and has an independent ApplicationContext (the interface that you use to get beans in your application).

Answer (score 0):

In order to scan `@Configuration` bean, you need to specify base packages to `@SpringBootApplication` then add the following line and it will work.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.github.fish56.modules.commons.config", 
                                           "com.github.fish56.modules"})
```

Comment: Hi, did you add this for ModulesApplication and ModulesApplicationTest as well?